# Multiple columns chart using asp.net chart control

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms, mschart

I need to show the data columns in multiple column chart,
I have used single column charts, but I cant find the way to bind another Y-Axis column to the chart

I have data in following format

```
Name      DataField-1    DataField-2
Emp-a     200               220
Emp-b     150               250
```

Comment: what is chtStudentResult here ?

Comment: It`s <asp:chart id="chtStudentResult" ...> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following link useful for the problem.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx

If any one have better suggestion than this please post.

Find another solution like following..

```
double[] array1 = { 2.8, 4.4, 6.5, 8.3, 3.6, 5.6, 7.3 };
double[] array2 = { 2.0, 4.0, 6.1, 7.8, 2.5, 5.0, 6.2 };

chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
chtStudentResult.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(array1);
chtStudentResult.Series.Add("Series2");
chtStudentResult.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindY(array2);
```

It will generate the desired multiple column, column chart.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy.

1. You just go to your properties of Chart control. There is a
   property called series.
2. Click on that and give the two series you need to show in the
   Chart. Eg: `DataField-1` , `DataField-2` in your case.
3. Then simply go to the chart and attach Data-Source to your chart
   control.
4. Then you will get two `XAxis` and `YAxis`.
5. Then select the correct axis values.