# Databind ObjectDataSource with multiple Y-values to MSChart

Tags: data-binding, mschart, design-time

I have a simple object datasource, in the form of an `IENumerable<MyClass>` where MyClass is :

```
class MyClass(){
    public DateTime Key;
    public Int Value1;
    public Int Value2;
    public Int Value3;
}
```

I wish to databind it using an ObjectDataSource at design time, not declaratively.
I would expect this to be:

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" DataSourceID="datasource">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series XValueMember="Key" YValueMembers="Value1"/>
        <asp:Series XValueMember="Key" YValueMembers="Value2"/>
    </Series>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="datasource" runat="server" SelectMethod="DataObjectMethodName" TypeName="DataObjectClassName"/>
```

Yet whenever I attempt to databind this mapping I receive the following exception:

`Series data points do not support values of MyClass only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.`

I also attempted to let my Datasource return a `Dictionary<DateTime, Int[]>` and `Dictionary<DateTime, MyClass>`, without success.

Is simple design-Time databinding to complex objects not supported for MSCharts? I was able to bind to a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>`.
In the end this should be a chart of type StackedColumn.

I've see similar questions, like [Multiple columns chart using asp.net chart control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476096/multiple-columns-chart-using-asp-net-chart-control) which do not answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions seem not to be so popular on SO.

I was unable to achive any real databinding. In order to be able to keep using the designer I just used a hack. I added one series to the designer, so I could use the drag and drop editor, easing my life. The I copied the values from the 'template' series.

```cs
    //Treat the one designer series as a template
    var template = chartFares.Series.First();
    //Just used for fancying up the designer and adding demo settings
    chartFares.Series.Clear(); 

    foreach (var series in serieses)
    {
        var chartSeries = chartFares.Series.Add(series.Name);

        //Copy setting from template (better cloning mechanism would also be useful)
        chartSeries.ChartType = template.ChartType;
        chartSeries.ToolTip = template.ToolTip;
        chartSeries.PostBackValue = template.PostBackValue;

        foreach (var points in series.Data)
        {
            chartSeries.Points.AddXY(points.Period, points.Count);
        }
    }
```